# Side scroll on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm seeing some nasty side scroll on mobile devices. I have two @media queries set, tablet and mobile.

[dev.bdbshop.com](http://www.dev.bdbshop.com/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.wrap { max-width: 300px; }
```

Is this the issue? Is there a better way to do this, e.g. use a percentage?

Should I add a third @media query and set more specific percentages? Currently there are only 2 break points that are rather wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code `<div id="sidebar-footer" class="sidebar">`
You know What is the exactly width of this element? You have used mentioned its width to more than viewport 100%.

`#sidebar-footer {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    width: 104.255%;
}`

Use 100% instead of 104.255% . It works fine with it.

Comment: That was it. Don't know how I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: I'm now seeing a larger side scroll issue on the internal post pages. Everything is floated left margin, but there's a substantial padding issue on the right

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up question, do you personally think it's worth it to add another #media screen break point lower then 767px? For instance 320px for older mobile & iPhone?